Implement Autosave in Ionic Angular For Mobile App
I was wondering if I can prompt user that their item is saved after they select payment dropdown.
But I was asked for a much more efficient way of prompting user in case they forgot to select payment dropdown.
Which library I can used for the autosave for Ionic Angular though, any suggestions would be great?
